# Custom cursor on click

Tags: javascript

I'm working on something and I want to change the cursor with a custom gif animation. The reason for this is the loading time. When I'm clicking a link it takes about 2 seconds to load and this is why i want to have a nice loadking cursor. Is there any way to change it with the `onClick()`?
Thanks for your time!

Edit: Because the loading occures between the 2 pages is it possible to change the loading mouse too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('a.cursor_wait').click(function(){
    jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
      $(this).css('cursor', 'wait');
  });
});
```

jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/3WLGt/4/)

Comment: This is only when im hovering over the link. I want something which changes the coursor completely

Comment: You can do it like; http://jsfiddle.net/3WLGt/148/

Comment: and how about a custom gif and automate it for every link?

Comment: You can give a path for gif. Code is http://jsfiddle.net/3WLGt/149/. If you want to it appear only on link, you can change jquery selector to "a" like $("a").css('cursor', 'url(link_of_gif), auto').